# How to set primefaces virtual keyboard?

Tags: jsf-2

1. Is there any option for primefaces keyboard component to accept numbers form both keyboard and mouse?
2. I'm using primefaces keyboard component with keypadonly option to enter numbers only.
   I should be able to enter numbers either from physical keyboard or virtual keyboard.
   If keypadonly is set to true, I'm not able to enter data using physical keyboard.
   I don't have this problem if keypadonly only attribute is not used. Did someone experience this problem? If so please let me know how to handle it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be intentional, if keypadonly is set to true a javascript will set the input to `readonly="readonly"`.
You may try to use a custom layout (see http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/keyboard.jsf ).
This migth work:

```
<p:keyboard value="#{keyboardBean.value}"   
                layout="custom"  
                layoutTemplate="123-close,456-clear,789-back,0"/>
```

or removing the readonly attribute with a custom javascript.